# `vendor/` sub-directory relationship to 3rd party dependencies

Tags: library

In the `-go-ethereum` client directory I've run the command `find . -name \*.md -print` looking for `README.md` files. The output is as follows:

```
    ./.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
    ./.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
    ./build/ci-notes.md
    ./contracts/ens/README.md
    ./crypto/secp256k1/libsecp256k1/README.md
    ./log/README.md
    ./log/README_ETHEREUM.md
    ./README.md
    ./swarm/dev/README.md
    ./vendor/bazil.org/fuse/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/aristanetworks/goarista/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/CHANGELOG.md
    ./vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-go/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/btcsuite/btcd/btcec/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/cespare/cp/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md
    ./vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/VERSION_HISTORY.md
    ./vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/reexec/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/edsrzf/mmap-go/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/fatih/color/LICENSE.md
    ./vendor/github.com/fatih/color/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/gizak/termui/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/go-stack/stack/LICENSE.md
    ./vendor/github.com/go-stack/stack/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/huin/goupnp/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/jackpal/go-nat-pmp/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/karalabe/hid/LICENSE.md
    ./vendor/github.com/karalabe/hid/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/maruel/panicparse/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/mattn/go-colorable/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/mattn/go-isatty/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/mitchellh/go-wordwrap/LICENSE.md
    ./vendor/github.com/mitchellh/go-wordwrap/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/naoina/go-stringutil/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/naoina/toml/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/nsf/termbox-go/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/olekukonko/tablewriter/LICENCE.md
    ./vendor/github.com/olekukonko/tablewriter/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/pborman/uuid/CONTRIBUTING.md
    ./vendor/github.com/pborman/uuid/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/peterh/liner/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/memory.md
    ./vendor/github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/rs/cors/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/rs/xhandler/README.md
    ./vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/README.md
    ./vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/CONTRIBUTING.md
    ./vendor/golang.org/x/net/CONTRIBUTING.md
    ./vendor/golang.org/x/sys/CONTRIBUTING.md
    ./vendor/golang.org/x/text/CONTRIBUTING.md
    ./vendor/golang.org/x/tools/CONTRIBUTING.md
    ./vendor/gopkg.in/check.v1/README.md
    ./vendor/gopkg.in/fatih/set.v0/LICENSE.md
    ./vendor/gopkg.in/fatih/set.v0/README.md
    ./vendor/gopkg.in/karalabe/cookiejar.v2/README.md
    ./vendor/gopkg.in/natefinch/npipe.v2/README.md
    ./vendor/gopkg.in/sourcemap.v1/README.md
    ./vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1/CHANGELOG.md
    ./vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1/README.md
```

Based on this it looks like all the "3rd party" dependencies are located in the `vendor/` directory. Is that the case? Why is this directory called as `vendor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on this it looks like all the "3rd party" dependencies are
>   located in the vendor/ directory. Is that the case?

Yes, correct.

> Why is this directory called as vendor?

This is a convention in Go, introduced in golang 1.6 (experimentally in 1.5).

See the official documentation, here: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories

In short:

> Go 1.6 includes support for using local copies of external
>   dependencies to satisfy imports of those dependencies, often referred
>   to as vendoring.
>
> Code below a directory named "vendor" is importable only by code in
>   the directory tree rooted at the parent of "vendor", and only using an
>   import path that omits the prefix up to and including the vendor
>   element.